# Using handlebars runtime library

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Can somebody help me with a sample code on how to use the handlebars runtime library (handlebars.runtime.js) please?

I have tried to use Handlebars.compile, which obviously does not work, because I know runtime library is to avoid compiling templates.

Also I have tried to use Handlebars.template method by passing the template as a string, but it is not working as the template method expects a function as a parameter.

I think I am doing something basically wrong. Are there any documentations on how to use runtime library on its own?

Much appreciate the help.

**More details:**
I first used handlebars.js file, which was working good, but my team-mate noticed the compressed file is too big (>40KB) for our purpose (just a few templates in our site).

So, I tried using just handlebars.runtime.js file. Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Here is the sample I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/2KfsM/

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script id="hb-example" type="text/handlebars-template">
  <p>{{sampleText}}</p>
</script>
```

The js piece:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile($('#hb-example').html());
$('#container').html(template({sampleText: 'Here is a sample'}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can really improve performance by precompiling your template. But, in order to use the handlebar runtime library you have to first compile your existing template.

There is no `Handlebars.compile` function available in the runtime library.

Here is some links:

http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html

http://berzniz.com/post/24743062344/handling-handlebars-js-like-a-pro

Comment: Thanks. Found this one, which gives better details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659787/using-pre-compiled-templates-with-handlebars-js-jquery-mobile-environment

Comment: wondering why there is no **good** documentation about precompilation in handlebarsjs.com