# TypeError applying precompiled Handlebars templates with a context

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

Pardon the noob question but I simply can't get precompiled Handlebars templates to do anything but barf out

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'templateSpec.call(container, Handlebars, context, options.helpers, options.partials, options.data)')

each time I apply a context to a (precompiled) template.

Given the following files and contents:

- *hello.handlebars*: `<p>Hello, {{name}}</p>`
- *templates.js*: the result of compiling *hello.handlebars* via `handlebars hello.handlebars -f templates.js`
- *index.html*: includes [Handlebars RC1 runtime](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/downloads) in the `head` and this for the body:

  ```
  <body id="body">
    <script src="templates.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.templates['hello'];
      var html = compiledTemplate({ name: 'World' });
      document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = html;
    </script>
  </body>
  ```

Calling `compiledTemplate()` throws that error above no matter what I do--yet I'm able to get client-side templates to compile and display just fine. All the walkthroughs and tutorials I've seen skip through this like its obvious so I must be missing something silly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 27):

Be sure to match the versions of the Handlebars server and client packages. A way to check the version of the compiled template is the following:

> handlebars a_template_of_yours.handlebars | grep "compilerInfo"

It should output something like this:

> this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];

The first value is the Compiler Revision, which should match the output of the following code on your browser:

> Handlebars.COMPILER_REVISION

If you used **npm** to download your Handlebars compiler, specify the version which you need. Here is an example for **handlebars.runtime-v1.3.0.js**:

> npm install handlebars@1.3.0 -g

Comment: This helped me. npm installed per default `handlebars-2.0.0-alpha`... which was not compatible to the runtime 1.3.0

Comment: I was running [the 1.0.rc.1](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/downloads) in both cases.

Comment: @ele, i would recommend you -if possible- to upgrade to a more recent version of Handlebars, since 1.0.rc.1 dates from September 2012. The latest stable version is 1.3.0 from January 2014, so there might be a lot of improvements you will also be missing.

You can download the latest stable client (i.e. the runtime js module) from [Handlebars Home](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

The node compiler (server module) can be downloaded from npm (specifying the version, to prevent downloading some new alpha version), or from the [Github releases site](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/releases).

Comment: `handlebars <pre-compiled or not-compiled template file> | grep "compilerInfo"` returned me anything. however, `handlebars <not-compiled template file> | grep "compiler"` returned me `,"...compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data,depths...` so it is 2.0.0 ? how that value came from a non-compiled template? I can't understand that.

Comment: This comment is old, but i'm answering for the record. Probably naming changed in that version of handlebars. Yours seems to be `2.0.0-beta.1`. That value came from the compiled template you are generating through executing the handlebars compiler with `handlebars <not-compiled template file>`. Later, the `grep "compiler"` looks for the text "compiler" in the output generated by the handlebars compiler, thanks to the pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

The problem for me is that currently (June 2014), the 2.0 release on GitHub is marked alpha https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/releases.

If I install handlebars via `bower`, it selects the latest stable release. `v1.3.0`.

`npm install handlebars`, however, installs the `~2.0.0-alpha.4` version.

**Solution:** update the version in `bower.json` to `~2.0.*`, and run `bower update`.