# Simple "server-side" HTML partials/templates/layouts?

Tags: html, ruby, node.js, build-process, partial

I'm working with two students to produce a few HTML pages (a homepage and two secondary page layouts) that will later be implemented into a larger CMS.

I'd like to be able to abstract the shared HTML (head metadata, primary navigation, footer, etc.) into separate files so we only have to update them in a single place, execute a shell command to generate new, complete output. Since these pages are only ever going to become templates for another team, I don't even need to integrate any external data sources.

I know Jade would work for this but our partials/layouts/whatever need to look like HTML. I keep coming back to precompiling Handlebars templates but [I'm not having much luck getting them to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21964023/1457116).

Since we're using Foundation 5, Ruby and Node are already part of our toolchain. Suggestions?

Comment: You can just use ERB, right?

Comment: Why not jade? This is exactly what it is usually used for.

Comment: I looked into ERB a bit but haven't used it before. Any suggestions for where to start?

Comment: I rather like Jade myself but we decided against it in this case because we want the templates to look like HTML (other than the includes/variables). I'm already throwing HTML, CSS, Sass, Compass and Git at these kids. Another syntax seemed a little much.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/) for this kind of thing. Layouts and partials and local data, etc. Wonderfully useful for doing front-end prototyping for what will eventually become a Rails application.