# TypeError: templateSpec.call is not a function

Tags: handlebars.js

How to fix handlebar issue with nodeJS

TypeError: templateSpec.call is not a function

Comment: Please post more information for us to be able to help debug it. Where are you rendering the template?

Comment: This fixed it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964023/typeerror-applying-precompiled-handlebars-templates-with-a-context

Comment: this is fixed for me. I was not using the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was pre-compiling my templates with a specific version and using them with a different version of runtime.

In my case, gulp-handlebars was using the edge version, and I had to install the version I needed and passed it to the gulp-handlebars configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If your following a tutorial that uses an old version of the handlebars runtime. Replace handlebars.runtime.js with the latest version from the handlebars website. 
I installed handlebars via npm and as soon as I used updated code, it worked perfectly.

[image]