# Precompiled handlebars template not working

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, precompiled

I precompiled my handlebars template like this:

```
 handlebars tabs.hbs -f tabs.js
```

I load them like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.runtime.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/templates/tabs.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabsData.js"></script>
```

This is how I provide the context to the precompiled template:

```
var template=Handlebars.templates["tabs.hbs"];
var html=template(tabsData);
console.log(html)
sidebar.setContent(html);
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function    handlebars.runtime.js 436
 /*Error points here*/
 var result = templateSpec.call(
        container,
        namespace, context,
        helpers,
        partials,
        options.data);
```

This is `template`:

```
  function (context, options) {
  options = options || {};
  var namespace = options.partial ? options : env,
      helpers,
      partials;

  if (!options.partial) {
    helpers = options.helpers;
    partials = options.partials;
  }
  var result = templateSpec.call(
        container,
        namespace, context,
        helpers,
        partials,
        options.data);

  if (!options.partial) {
    env.VM.checkRevision(container.compilerInfo);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to figure out which item is undefined.

Comment: @MikeCheel Calling `template(tabsData)` throws this `error`,I trying using the same `context` and compiling it on `tryhandlebarsjs.com` where it works.

Comment: What do u get for console.log(template)

Comment: @blessenm Added the `template` code...

Comment: I think Handlebars.templates["tabs.hbs"] is returning undefined. Check if Handlebars.templates has ur template and if the key 'tabs.hbs' si correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [biomorgoth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386306/biomorgoth) commented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22214119

Make sure your npm version corresponds to the client version. Client version is in the the top of the js file and you find npm version with:

```
npm list -g | grep handlebars
```

installing the 1.3.0 version with npm solved the issue for me.

```
sudo npm install -g handlebars@1.3.0
```